# is a matching __sync_lock_release mandatory?

Tags: c, gnu, built-in, memory-barriers

I am reviewing some circa 2013 C code that uses __sync_xxx built-ins. Mostly these look fine but in one case I found a __sync_lock_test_and_set() without __sync_lock_release(). It looks like the original programmer was using __sync_lock_test_and_set() as an atomic store for pointer values in a hash table. The code doesn't wait on these memory locations (e.g. check the __sync_lock_test_and_set result in a while loop), it just sets them and moves on. Searching on "is __sync_lock_release mandatory" and similar isn't bringing up a clear answer (although that does bring up useful discussions [1][2] making clear the newer GNU atomic built-ins should be used, and I may be able to convince the client to do that).

What problem might be caused by not calling __sync_lock_release() and releasing an acquire memory barrier?  Do such barriers "survive" in any way and possibly affect other code?

[1] [What is the GCC builtin for an atomic set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932746/what-is-the-gcc-builtin-for-an-atomic-set)
[2] [Is my spin lock implementation correct and optimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383363/is-my-spin-lock-implementation-correct-and-optimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory barriers (or memory orders for operations) aren't things you have to release in the first place. See  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ / https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences

`release` is one of the possible orderings an operation can have, one that's appropriate for releasing a lock but also for the writing side of acquire/release synchronization.

An `acquire` operation is one you could use in implementing a function that takes a lock.  There isn't a hidden lock anywhere that gets taken behind the scenes.  (A non-lock-free implementation of `__sync` or `__atomic` builtins might [use a lock internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298358/where-is-the-lock-for-a-stdatomic), but it would take and release it within one invocation of the builtin.)

`void __sync_lock_release (ptr, 0)` is just `__atomic_store_explicit(ptr, 0, __ATOMIC_RELEASE)`.  (Actually the docs call it a "barrier", not just an operation with ordering wrt. other operations, so perhaps `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)` and then a relaxed atomic store.

**The documentation wording of "*This built-in function releases the lock acquired by `__sync_lock_test_and_set`.*" is just an example use-case, there is no resource or lock that "needs to be released".**

---

All legacy `__sync` builtins are like `__atomic_...(__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)`, except apparently for `__sync_lock_test_and_set` and `__sync_lock_release`; this is the only reason there's a special function with `release` in the name, because the old `sync` builtins didn't generally allow release operations.

If the code only wants to do `atomic_exchange_explicit(ptr, 1, memory_order_acquire)` at that point, that's totally fine and normal, and it can do it with an obsolete `__sync_lock_test_and_set` if it wants.

---

If you were going to rewrite anything, use C11 `stdatomic.h`, or use `__atomic` builtins if you don't want to make the array `_Atomic`.  Either way, figure out if acquire ordering for that operation is appropriate, and if not use a weaker or stronger order, whatever is required.  On x86, any atomic RMW will effectively be `seq_cst` except for possible compile-time reordering of weaker orders.

Comment: Peter thanks. My worry level is back to normal. I'm accepting your answer

Comment: @JeffBrower: Forgot to mention in the answer: if they just need an atomic store, not RMW, that's *much* more efficient with `__atomic_store_n` or C11 `atomic_store_explicit` (with an order weaker than seq_cst), not an RMW.